# How can I have a verbatim text in specific sized box?

Tags: boxes, verbatim

I am trying to typset the following

```
\resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{verbatim}
  require( "lattice" )
  require( "grid" )
 \end{verbatim}
}
```

I have a lot more to add to this box, and it needs to be typset `verbatim`, but it gives me an error.  Am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not use verbatim in the argument to another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\myv

\begin{lrbox}{\myv}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}

\resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\myv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this still gives a error, albeit a new one :).  So I should put in everything i want into the `lrbox` and then typeset the document?

Comment: You should _always_ include complete documents in the question. I just made a complete document in my answer, that should run without error, if yours does not there is a difference somewhere

Comment: i accept my mistake.  But thank you for answering the question.  I think this solves the problem.

Comment: The reason `verbatim` cannot be used in the argument to another command is specific to this package, or is there a more general rule about LaTeX that I'm missing here?

Comment: @astrojuanlu verbatim (and all similar commands (verb, listings, minted, etc) can not be used  in an argument as they affect the way characters are tokenized, but arguments are tokenized before the macro is expanded so changing the rules after that has no effect. How could it work otherwise. verbatim makes `{}` not special but in `\foo{\begin{verbatim}....\end{verbatim}}` you are relying on `{}` being parsed and matched with normal special meaning in order to find the closing `}`.

Answer (score 9):

If what you want is to reduce the size of the font used in `verbatim`, you can use the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
This will be verbatim at \small size
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If you also want to shift a bit the verbatim text, use also the key `xleftmargin`, for instance

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small,xleftmargin=\parindent]
```

If you say

```
\fvset{fontsize=\small,xleftmargin=\parindent}
```

all you need in the document is

```
\begin{Verbatim}
```

(but you can countermand the global settings by specifying other values in the optional argument).

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{myVerb}
  require( "lattice" )
  require( "grid" )
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{\BUseVerbatim{myVerb}}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is much simpler, but i like the previous answer by David Carlisle, because it does not require me to use additional packages.  I also think this solution is more generic.

Comment: This answer does exactly what I want and is clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

There is the `verbatimbox` package that puts verbatim in a box

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
 \begin{verbbox}
  require( "lattice" )
  require( "grid" )
 \end{verbbox}
\resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```