# To eliminate sparse-columns in Logical Tables?

Tags: tables, minimal

Pseudocode

```
\begin{verbatim} % verbatim is secondary to this problem; choose whatever suits you best!
\begin{minimalSparse}[space=0.5]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microangiopathy                     Diagnosis                       Treatment
---------------------------------   ------------------------------  ----------------------------
1. Diabetic Retinopathy:                                         
a) non proferative,                 connective tissues much,        Treat glycemia,
b) proferative,                     not much blood vessels            LF, 
c) maculopathy                                                        VEGFi
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{minimalSparse}
\end{verbatim}
```

where the new environment should not affect the *verbatim* so it is inside it. 
However, you do not need to use verbatim if you do not want to. 
This case (sparse-column minimization and view) can be handled by one environment too; however, I splitted the minimization to one environment and the view to another environment (*verbatim*) because I think data processing and view should not be incorporated in one package. 
The *minimalSparse* is about minimizing the non-textual environment between columns by:

- vertical white columns of data where only underscores (_) and spaces; David proposes just a Perl script for this. Feel free to propose something about it.
- *space* parameter is about reducing the amount of empty spaces between columns so *space=0.5* is the reduction by 50%.

Example methods to decrease white space where data used from the linked thread:

[image]

where the example data about logical tables is in [How to show Full Verbatim/Pandoc table in one page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269486/13173)
Instead of showing full verbatim/pandoc table in one page, I would like to minimize the sparse space around logical tables by eliminating the columns having only underscores (_) in the data. 
Options such as *minipage* and font-size reduction (`fancyvrb` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86904/13173)) do not target only the white space, so they are not wanted.

---

How can you minimize sparse space of some environment in LaTeX?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the question. You want to shrink the white space? That would make the data beeing scrambled like broken eggs. You cannot fit an elephant in a suitcase.

Comment: In the pseudocode, I want to minimize the white space by 50%. In some contexes, there are too much white space. In those cases, the minimization would be usuful. Sometimes, an elephant is not an elephant, but a mouse that wants to an elephant so I think it is possible.

Comment: You showed a screenshot in the other question (is it a dupe, didn't check) and use Paint (or whatever) and mark the qhite space you are talking about. I really don't understand what you want.

Comment: Is your real question: *I want to include a pdf with a  big table  in my document?*

Comment: No. Including a pdf with a big table in my document, is not the question.

Comment: This question is completely unclear. The only relevant space I can see in the example is the word space between `data` and `here` Do you want to reduce that (which is possible) But what do you mean by "sparse" ???? Also you have it inside a verbatim environment but seem to be implying that `\begin{minimalSparse}[space=0.5]` something? If it is going to affect the setting of the verbatim it should be _outside_ (surrounding) the verbatim.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By sparse, I mean space between columns, for instance, where is no textual environment. It is only pseudocode for reducing such a space by 50%. It should not affect the setting of the verbatim so it should be inside verbatim.

Comment: @Masi it makes no sense being inside the verbatim, if you want verbatim to be small you use  `{\small\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}}` you don't use `\begin{verbatim}\small..\end{verbatim}` as then, by definition `\small` is not a command but just text set verbatim.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Verbatim environment is secondary here. It is just an example where you can show the output. I do not want to affect systematically all the environment in the context, like `\small` does. If you have better idea about appropriate environment for such a task, please answer.

Comment: If you remove the *column containing only underscores*, the header line (Microangiopathy, Diagnosis) will not be unique fields anymore.

Comment: @Masi sorry the question just isn't clear enough to suggest any answer at all. If you just have an ascii table you want to set verbatim, why not edit it perl before including it verbatim (if that isn't what you mean, I really can't guess, sorry)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you please give an example of such an Perl?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl You could also use `sed` or `awk` or `python` or .... to remove those underscores.

Comment: Of course, I know what is Perl. Are you really proposing making a parser for this issue. There must be a better way!

Comment: To be honest, i still don't understand the point of the question. I think it is best to make a standalone document and include it using `pdfpages`. You aren't printing that anyway.